# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, sockets, typeerror, python-module, callable

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Mibot\oops\blinkserv.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.serv = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Why am I getting this error?
I'm confused.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I once got this error because I had both a (global) variable and a function with the same name.

Comment: I got this error with file name pointed to random.py in the same folder where I had a previously worked ipynb file. I changed the name of the file to random_function.py and relaunched the jupyter notebook. The error disappeared. To test if the name random.py was the problem, I changed the file random_function.py back to random.py. The problem came back.

Dont name your file after name of a python library.

Answer (score 810):

`socket` is a module, containing the class `socket`.

You need to do `socket.socket(...)` or `from socket import socket`:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket
<module 'socket' from 'C:\Python27\lib\socket.pyc'>
>>> socket.socket
<class 'socket._socketobject'>
>>>
>>> from socket import socket
>>> socket
<class 'socket._socketobject'>
```

This is what the error message means:
It says `module object is not callable`, because your code is calling a *module* object. A module object is the type of thing you get when you import a module. What you were trying to do is to call a *class* object within the module object that happens to have the same name as the module that contains it.

Here is a way to logically break down this sort of error:

- "`module object is not callable`. Python is telling me my code trying to call something that cannot be called. What is my code trying to call?"
- "The code is trying to call on `socket`. That should be callable! Is the variable `socket` is what I think it is?`
- I should print out what socket is and check `print(socket)`

Comment: I currently am imporitng socket like this: from socket import *

Comment: I also changed it to from socket import socket and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @user: if you do `print socket` you'll see that the name `socket` is a module. It has to have been bound to that module _somewhere_! Read through your code carefully and I'm sure you'll see an `import socket` or some such where you don't expect it.

Comment: Ohh I get it. The `socket.socket` was a little confusing. I simply did `import write_to_file` and then, since the method I was using inside of `write_to_file.py` is named `writeToTextFile` I simply rand `write_to_file.writeToTextFile`

Comment: It's worth noting that this wasn't obvious to at least 133 people who took time to up vote (myself included) who didn't understand this. Now, it's obvious, and next time I reach in my toolbox, I will find this tool when a module is reported as "not callable". Getting started with a new language is the toughest part.

Comment: I am coding in Python for 1 day and i wanted to find a method to call classes dinamicaly .... no person said what globals()[] gives you. It doesn't give the class it gives the module ... which is the import file

Comment: @maudulus I don't find Python very user-friendly in these respects.

Comment: Why on earth someone would ever want to have a "handle" to the module itself (which is just a source code file), rather than the class defined in it, in the first place? What is the use case for that?

Comment: @AntonSamsonov For example in order to have a plugin system which requires an object be given with a certain attribute (or several), e. g. "init" as an entry point. In this case, you can pass a class, an object or a module to this plugin system.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov It also enables you to have several classes in one file of a different name. So I can import a class from, say, a `DbHelperClasses` file and only import the `DBConnectionHelper` class within that file. Even though the file may have several other classes that I don't need.

Comment: "I don't find Python very user-friendly in these respects" What should it do instead?

Comment: @AntonSamsonov for the same reason that one would use, for example, a namespace in C++ or C# code.

Comment: @LucianTarna `globals()['x']` gives you whatever the global name `x` refers to. If that's "the class", it will give you "the class". If that's "the module", it will give you "the module". If that's some random integer or string, you get that instead.

Answer (score 341):

Assume that the content of **YourClass.py** is:

```
class YourClass:
    # ......
```

If you use:

```
from YourClassParentDir import YourClass  # means YourClass.py
```

In this way, you will get **TypeError: 'module' object is not callable** if you then tried to call `YourClass()`.

But, if you use:

```
from YourClassParentDir.YourClass import YourClass   # means Class YourClass
```

or use `YourClass.YourClass()`, it works.

Comment: class = YourClass.YourClass()

Comment: I solved this issue by using from yourClass import *

Comment: Best answer, i need to look more into the namespaces imports in python

Answer (score 135):

Add to the main `__init__.py` in YourClassParentDir, e.g.:

```
from .YourClass import YourClass
```

Then, you will have an instance of your class ready when you import it into another script:

```
from YourClassParentDir import YourClass
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be
  `from .YourClass import YourClass`
 in the `__init__.py` file ?

Answer (score 59):

Short answer: **You are calling a file/directory as a function instead of real function**

Read on:

This kind of error happens when you import module thinking it as function and call it.
So in python module is a .py file. Packages(directories) can also be considered as modules.
Let's say I have a **create.py** file. In that file I have  a function like this:

```
#inside create.py
def create():
  pass
```

Now, in another code file if I do like this:

```
#inside main.py file
import create
create() #here create refers to create.py , so create.create() would work here
```

It gives this error as am calling the create.py file as a function.
so I gotta do this:

```
from create import create
create() #now it works.
```

Answer (score 38):

Here is another gotcha, that took me awhile to see even after reading these posts. I was setting up a script to call my python bin scripts. I was getting the module not callable too.

My zig was that I was doing the following:

```
from mypackage.bin import myscript
...
myscript(...)
```

when my zag needed to do the following:

```
from mypackage.bin.myscript import myscript
...
myscript(...)
```

In summary, double check your package and module nesting.

What I am trying to do is have a scripts directory that does not have the *.py extension, and still have the 'bin' modules to be in mypackage/bin and these have my *.py extension. I am new to packaging, and trying to follow the standards as I am interpreting them. So, I have at the setup root:

```
setup.py
scripts/
      script1
mypackage/
   bin/
      script1.py
   subpackage1/
   subpackage_etc/
```

If this is not compliant with standard, please let me know.

Answer (score 24):

It seems like what you've done is imported the `socket` module as `import socket`. Therefore `socket` is the module. You either need to change that line to `self.serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`, as well as every other use of the `socket` module, or change the import statement to `from socket import socket`.

Or you've got an `import socket` after your `from socket import *`:

```
>>> from socket import *
>>> serv = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
>>> import socket
>>> serv = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: I've imported socket as: from socket import *  I can change it, but it'll take a while, so I'm reluctant to.

Comment: @user You've probably later somewhere got an `import socket`, which will import the module `socket` overriding the class `socket`. See code snippet in edit.

Comment: @user: you should change it. The reason `from <...> import *` imports are __bad, bad, bad__ is more or less this: normally you know exactly what's in the global namespace, because it's exactly what you've put there. But when you `import *`, you fill that namespace with all sorts of stuff that other modules define. In this case, it's unclear where the name `socket` came from -- is it the module or something defined in that module? If you _always_ use `import socket` or `from socket import socket`, you will never have this problem, since you can see exactly what names are in use.

Answer (score 8):

I know this thread is a year old, but the real problem is in your working directory.

I believe that the working directory is `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Mibot\oops\`. Please check for the file named `socket.py` in this directory. Once you find it, rename or move it. When you import socket, `socket.py` from the current directory is used instead of the `socket.py` from Python's directory. Hope this helped. :)

**Note:** Never use the file names from Python's directory to save your program's file name; it will conflict with your program(s).

Comment: This is definitely worth noting. I was just trying a quick check with sockets so I simply named the file `socket.py`. Well, that was causing this exact same error message. This page put me on the right track: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible extra edge case that I stumbled upon and was puzzled by for a while, hope it helps someone:

In `some_module/a.py`:

```py
def a():
   pass
```

In `some_module/b.py`:

```py
from . import a

def b():
   a()
```

In `some_module/__init__.py`:

```py
from .b import b
from .a import a
```

`main.py`:

```py
from some_module import b

b()
```

Then because when main.py loads b, it goes via `__init__.py` which tries to load `b.py` before `a.py`. This means when `b.py` tries to load `a` it gets the module rather than the function - meaning you'll get the error message `module object is not callable`

The solution here is to swap the order in `some_module/__init__.py`:

```py
from .a import a
from .b import b
```

Or, if this would create a circular dependency, change your file names to not match the functions, and load directly from the files rather than relying on `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

When configuring an console_scripts entrypoint in setup.py I found this issue existed when the endpoint was a module or package rather than a function within the module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/virtualenv/bin/mycli", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('my-package', 'console_scripts', 'mycli')()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

For example

```
from setuptools import setup
setup (
# ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [mycli=package.module.submodule]
    },
# ...
)
```

Should have been

```
from setuptools import setup
setup (
# ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [mycli=package.module.submodule:main]
    },
# ...
)
```

So that it would refer to a callable function rather than the module itself. It seems to make no difference if the module has a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. This will not make the module callable.

Comment: an alternative is to use the `scripts` parameter instead of `entry_points`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. then I tried not using
`from YourClass import YourClass`

I just copied the whole code of YourClass.py and run it on the main code (or current code).it solved the error

Comment: Well, that does work... However, you have just partially replaced a compiler (technically an interpreter) while cluttering up your codebase...
Also, I'm not sure this would work for binary-coded files (at least, not without some extra work)...

Answer (score 1):

you are using the name of a module instead of the name of the class
use

```
import socket
```

and then

```
socket.socket(...)
```

its a weird thing with the module, but you can also use something like

```
import socket as sock
```

and then use

```
sock.socket(...)
```

Comment: That answer was already given and highly upvoted 11 years ago. You can upvote one of the existing similar answer if you want to confirm it. But please, when answering to old question, be sure to bring new information that was not already given in existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error below:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

When calling [time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) to print as shown below:

```py
import time

print(time()) # Here
```

So to solve the error, I called `time.time()` as shown below:

```py
import time

print(time.time()) # Here
```

Or, I imported `time` from [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) as shown below:

```py
from time import time # Here

print(time())
```

Also, I got the same error in Django View because I use `@transaction` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import transaction
# ↓ Here ↓
@transaction
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So to solve the error, I use `@transaction.atomic` as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import transaction
# ↓ Here ↓
@transaction.atomic
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have overridden the builtin function/variable or something else "module" by setting the global variable "module". just print the module see whats in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was trying to use optuna (a library for hyperparameter tuning) with LightGBM. After an hour struggle I realized that I was importing class directly and that was creating an issue.

```
import lightgbm as lgb

def LGB_Objective(trial):
        parameters = {
            'objective_type': 'regression',
            'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 10, 60),
            'boosting': trial.suggest_categorical('boosting', ['gbdt', 'rf', 'dart']),
            'data_sample_strategy': 'bagging',
            'num_iterations': trial.suggest_int('num_iterations', 50, 250),
            'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 1.0),
            'reg_alpha': trial.suggest_float('reg_alpha', 0.01, 1.0), 
            'reg_lambda': trial.suggest_float('reg_lambda', 0.01, 1.0)
            }
        
        '''.....LightGBM model....''' 
        model_lgb = lgb(**parameters)
        model_lgb.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_pred = model_lgb.predict(x_test)
        return mse(y_test, y_pred, squared=True)

study_lgb = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize', study_name='lgb_regression') 
study_lgb.optimize(LGB_Objective, n_trials=200)
```

Here, the line `model_lgb = lgb(**parameters)` was trying to call the cLass itself.
When I digged into the `__init__.py` file in site_packages folder of LGB installation as below, I identified the module which was fit to me (I was working on regression problem). I therefore imported LGBMRegressor and replaced *lgb* in my code with *LGBMRegressor* and it started working.

[image]

You can check in your code if you are importing the entire class/directory (by mistake) or the target module within the class.

```
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor

def LGB_Objective(trial):
        parameters = {
            'objective_type': 'regression',
            'max_depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 10, 60),
            'boosting': trial.suggest_categorical('boosting', ['gbdt', 'rf', 'dart']),
            'data_sample_strategy': 'bagging',
            'num_iterations': trial.suggest_int('num_iterations', 50, 250),
            'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 1.0),
            'reg_alpha': trial.suggest_float('reg_alpha', 0.01, 1.0), 
            'reg_lambda': trial.suggest_float('reg_lambda', 0.01, 1.0)
            }
        
        '''.....LightGBM model....''' 
        model_lgb = LGBMRegressor(**parameters) #here I've changed lgb to LGBMRegressor
        model_lgb.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_pred = model_lgb.predict(x_test)
        return mse(y_test, y_pred, squared=True)

study_lgb = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize', study_name='lgb_regression') 
study_lgb.optimize(LGB_Objective, n_trials=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case try it

```
    from socket import socket
```

in addition

```
    #in a separate file you define a class like:

    class one:
              def __init__(self, name, value):
               self.name = name
               self.value = value
              pass

    #and in other file you define a other class.
    #and you want use defined class inside it.like:
    
    from one import one as clsOne #this model of import a class solve the error
    class two:
              item = clsOne("A", 22)
              print(item.name)
             pass
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to solve this problem is export the`PYTHONPATH` variable enviroment. For example, for Python 2.6 in Debian/GNU Linux:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6`
```

In other operating systems, you would first find the location of this module or the `socket.py` file.

Answer (score -3):

check the import statements since a module is not callable.
In Python, everything (including functions, methods, modules, classes etc.) is an object.

Comment: "Check the import statements" - Could you please be **any** bit more specific? At all? Please?