# Error with __init__ 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python

I was creating my module and when I tested it, I got an error.
The code was like this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,size,type):
        self.type = type
        self.size = size
```

And after I import the module, when I type:

```
x=test(10,'A type')
```

It says:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You didn't paste your import, but I'm betting you used

```
import test
```

where your file is called `test.py` (which should probably be more descriptive, BTW) which imports the *module*, which is why it's objecting that test is a module object and isn't callable.  You can access your class by calling

```
x = test.test(10, "A type")
```

or alternatively you could use

```
from test import test
```

after which

```
x = test(10, "A type")
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

Not the problem in this case, but if you get this error make sure you spelled **init** correctly. I had **int** with a missing i and it took awhile to notice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an indent problem.

Try indenting the def.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, size, type):
        self.type = type
        self.size = size
```

Comment: the code is indented properly in the source .. the OP just didn't format it correctly when he wrote his question (click `edit` to view the source). He should correct it though.

Comment: Eh, I see someone fixed it now. I was wondering how he got the parser to accept that.