# Why is 'module' object not callable?

Tags: python, object, module, callable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TypeError: ‘module’ object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

This is my very first Python attempt, just trying to regain basic programming knowledge after a 10 year silence in a, for me, new language, Python. The basic idea is a tiny battly engine which decides the better hit. The bugging code is next.

```
self.__power = self.__att*random(2,4)/dier.__defn
```

As my python knowledge is extremely basic, I'm rather scared of saying the right things so Im gonna put my code down below (47 lines), you..ll notice it is really transparant so I dont suspect this will give any problem. The errorline is 16. I tried renaming the att variable to atta as well as some repositionings though new bugs come, I solve them and in the end its always the same error on the same line.

```
class Character:
def __init__(self,name="", att=0,defn=0,lvl=0,leven=0,exp=0, power=0):
        self.__att = att
        self.__defn = defn
        self.__lvl = lvl
        self.__leven = leven
        self.__name = name
        self.__xp = exp
        self.__power = power

    def batl(self):
        import random
        while self.__lvl <= 3:
            dier = Character("Anaconda",1,1,50,1,0,0)
            print "You encountered an " + dier.__name + " and fight it."
            **self.__power = self.__att*random(2,4)/dier.__defn**
            dier.__power = (dier.__att*random(1,4))/self.__defn
            if self.power > dier.power:
                growth = dier.__lvl*dier.__atta
                groei()
            else:
                dmg = dier.lvl*dier.att
                leven = leven-dmg
            if leven < 0:
                print "Alas, you're done for."
                exit()
            else:
                print "You took " + dmg + "damage and have " + leven + "life left."


    def groei(self):
        if (growth+exp) > 100:
            lvl += 1
            exp = growth-100
            print "You won and gained " + str(growth) + " and grew from level " + str(lvl-1) + " to level " + str(lvl) + "."
        else:
            exp = growth + exp
            print "You won and gained " + str(growth) + "."
```

def main():

```
hero = Character("Nevery",2,1,2,100,0,0)
hero.batl()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()

As you can see ive got my character class, in which i have defined the battle() method and the groei() method, very basic. Can anyone point me what I'm missing out on, been looking at it for hours. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The error traceback will be much more informative than your code.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python because you really don't want `self.__att`

Comment: Too much leading double underscores. One is enough - and even that might be one too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) is the module, not the function.  You need to call [`random.random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random).  You could also `from random import random`, but I'd go with the first option in this case.

Comment: thanks :) i kept the import random and put (self.__att*random.randrange(2,4))/dier.__defn - works out fine now

Answer (score 1):

Use `random.random()` instead of `random`?