# Vagrant, WSGI, virtualenv and TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, virtualenv, vagrant

I've provisioned a vagrant box for an app I'm building, but I'm running into trouble when trying to get Apache to serve it.

It's using a virtualenv for it's packages - right now that's just Flask and it's dependencies, and that's all working fine. I can SSH in and run the app within the env. The app itself is just the [minimal application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) for now.

**Apache error**

```
[Sun Mar 31 10:06:54 2013] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] mod_wsgi (pid=1587): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/vagrant/myapp/myapp.wsgi'.
[Sun Mar 31 10:06:54 2013] [error] [client 10.0.2.2] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**Files**

```
/vagrant
├── env
└── myapp
    ├── app.py
    └── myapp.wsgi
```

**myapp.wsgi**

```py
activate_this = '/vagrant/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/vagrant/myapp')

import app as application
```

**Default site vhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /vagrant/myapp/myapp.wsgi

        <Directory /vagrant/myapp>
                WSGIProcessGroup myapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried running Apache with the user and group `vagrant` and chowning the site-packages and app dir to `www-data`. I've also tried changing the WSGIDaemon user and group to vagrant.

I've tried adding the site-packages to the path, and I've tried adding `__init__.py` to myapp and changing `myapp.wsgi` to `from myapp import app as application`.

The app can be run with `source ../env/bin/activate && python app.py`.

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem I had was in the wsgi file because I was importing the app package but not the class therein (caught out because they were named the same.)

```
activate_this = '/vagrant/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/vagrant/myapp')

from app import app as application
```

Note the final line has changed from `import app as application`.

Comment: <3 thanks! turned interwebz upside down to get python3+flask+pyvenv to work and this nailed last problem I had:)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that problem arises because you are using a shared folder as storage for your app source code which has a file system that behaves a bit different like normal ext3/4 so Apache and/or `chown` have a problem with it when it comes to more than just file copying...

Edit: although I'm only a python beginner maybe [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable) helps you with your problem