# How do I solve a TypeError module

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, arguments

I use sqlite3 as database.

I'm trying to execute my SQL query :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (application, version, path, os, user, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
args = my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass().getuser(), machine

c.execute(sql, args)
```

but I have this error :

```
args = my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass().getuser(), machine
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I already saw this post : [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable), but they spoke about socket.

Comment: The error is the same as in the post you saw, just with a different module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getpass` is a module, and you are calling it:

```
getpass().getuser()
```

Remove the first `()`:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> getpass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>> getpass.getuser()
'mj'
```

Comment: honestly, you surprise me ... I have posted an another question few hours ago, and no one gave me a correct answer (I knew it was not a problem of SQL syntax).

Comment: @Glacius: the previous question I can see was a Python string syntax error. I note that the answer there uses `getpass` correctly, btw.