# Python code has an error: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, api, autodesk

I try to coonect to API of Autodesk Inventor with Python. I can create a new file but then an error aooears here:

```
import os
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants
from win32com.client import gencache
os.system(r'C://Programm Files/Autodesk/Inventor 2014/Bin/Inventor.exe')
invApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Inventor.Application")
invApp.Visible = True
mod = gencache.EnsureModule('{D98A091D-3A0F-4C3E-B36E-61F62068D488}', 0, 1, 0)
**invApp = mod.Application(invApp)** 

oAssemblyDoc=invApp.Documents.Add(constants.kAssemblyDocumentObject, "", True)

asd = invApp.Documents.Add(constants.kPartDocumentObject,"",True)
qwe=invApp.Documents.Item(asd)
oAss = oAssemblyDoc.Activate
```

There ir an error in the selected line:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am a novice in Python and I can't understand what is the error. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Maybe look at solution to the same related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4534443/4716013

Comment: Can you make it clearer what line the error is occurring on?

Comment: in this line **invApp = mod.Application(invApp)**

Comment: despite the Inventor API may work with Python, I believe it was not tested at all... the main samples are in VB6/VBA and .NET, see the blogs at http://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/ and http://modthemachine.typepad.com

Answer (score 0):

I see that the win32com gencache early binding produces some subfolders. This seems to work with:

```
invApp = mod.Application.Application(invApp)
```

I found that `makepy.py` had to be run with `-i` command option first time, then re-run to capture the full structure.