# May be a duplicate - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, module, typeerror

I have been working with Python for about a year now, and I'm starting to write my own modules. I'm trying to make a module that imports a bunch of useful modules at the same time. The module imports fine. When I try to run it, it gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
        importuseful()
TypeError: 'module' object not callable
```

My file name is importuseful.py
My code is:

```
def importuseful():

    import sys

    import os

    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

    import GPIO as gpio

    import random

    import math

    import time

    import email

    import tty

    import turtle
```

I run at the IDLE shell:

> > > from Modules import importuseful
> > >
> > > importuseful()

Here is where it throws the TypeError

The path it is in is /home/pi/Modules, and that is set as part of $PYTHONPATH.

The only other module I have made is GPIO which is one I am trying to import. I was having the same problem with that one, but that one fixed itself.
    Anyone have any ideas on what is wrong or how to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: could you also give the code of how you wrote the module.

Comment: You should search before asking a question; the duplicate is showing up in the 'Related' list :).

Comment: @Cyphase, I read that one before posting, and I tried what it said, and it didn't work. I now realize why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the function using the module name, you have imported the module so `importuseful()` is trying to call the module not the function defined in your module:

```
 importuseful.importuseful()
```

Or if you wanted to import the function from the module, you would use:

```
 from importuseful import importuseful
 importuseful()
```

Or using your Modules:

```
 from Modules.importuseful import importuseful
```

If you are trying to actually import all the modules using the script. forget the function and just do the imports.

```
import sys
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import GPIO as gpio
import random
import math
import time
import email
import tty
import turtle
```

Then if you want to be able to use all the modules just use `importuseful.math` etc... You can use from `from Modules.importuseful import *` but that is never rarely a good idea, what you can so is shorten the name  `from Modules.importuseful import importuseful  as im` the `im.math(..` etc..

Comment: @Ryan, yes, you have to use the module name to access anything defined in it unless you actually import the functions from the module as in the second example, you could also `from Modules.importuseful import importuseful `

Comment: It seems like it did not import the wanted modules. It ran the module with no error, but did not import them.

Comment: If it did not error then it did import, are you trying to actually access what is inside the function or use the function?

Answer (score 0):

As [Padraic Cunningham said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061491/892383), you need to call the function inside the module.

```
from Modules import importuseful

importuseful.importuseful()
```

However, this isn't going to do what you want, because the modules will only be imported in the function scope. For instance:

```
>>> def importuseful():
...     import math
... 
>>> importuseful()
>>> math
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
>>>
```

You should just include only the modules you need at the top of every file. No need to import unnecessary modules.

If you *really* want to do this (which I don't recommend), you could put the imports directly into a module, then import everything from that module.

```
# usefulimports.py

import functools
import itertools
import math

# script.py

from usefulimports import *
```

Comment: Ok. I see how it works now. Thanks for explaining it.

Comment: @Ryan, I added a way to do what you want, though I still don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, I may modify the functions it imports to ones I know I will need in programs, so there are no unnecessary ones.

Comment: @Ryan, why not just have the imports directly in the file that's using them? Why separate them out into this other file?

Comment: When working with the GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi, I always use RPi.GPIO, GPIO, time, and math. I think it is faster to import everything from an external file, than import them all by hand every time.

Comment: Faster? By hand? I assume you mean in the REPL, not in a script. If so, I see where you're coming from in doing this. I'd just recommend not doing it in a script, where you just have to type it once :).