# Dynamic loading of classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance

My goal is to load dynamically my different subclasses and execute them. To call my script, I am using this:

```
python Plugin.py Nmap execute google.com
```

Or

```
python Plugin.py Dig execute google.com
```

Here it's the code

**Parent Class: Plugin.py**

```
class Plugin(object)
    def __init__(self):
        self.sName = ''
    def execPlugin(self):
        return 'something'
def main():
    # get the name of the plugin
    sPlugin = sys.argv[1]
    # create the object
    mMod = __import__(sPlugin, fromlist=[sPlugin])
    mInstance = getattr(mMod, sPlugin)
    oPlugin = mInstance()
    print oPlugin
    print type(oPlugin)
    if (sys.argv[2] == 'execute'):
        # then execute it
        return oPlugin.execPlugin(sys.argv[3])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Sub Class located in Nmap/Nmap.py**

```
class Nmap(Plugin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sName = 'Nmap'
    def execPlugin(self):
        return 'something else'
```

**Sub Class located in Dig/Dig.py**

```
class Dig(Plugin):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sName = 'Dig'
    def execPlugin(self):
        return 'yeahhh'
```

My problem is located in

```
oPlugin = mInstance()
```

With the following error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried so many things but nothing worked. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Have you imported a module named `mInstance`?

Comment: Why are `Nmap.py` and `Dig.py` in subdirectories? Do they have `__init__.py` files, and what's in those? You probably want another level of `getattr` to get the classes rather than the modules, or to simplify your structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: Yes, I have an __init__.py (empty) in my subdirectories and I need them for another reasons. I

Comment: What happens if you e.g. `from Nmap import Nmap` in the `__init__.py` in `/Nmap`? I think that would fix it.

Comment: I have a (new) error but I think we're close: Plugin.__init__()
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Plugin instance as first argument (got nothing instead). I am gonna investigate!

Comment: Then it's because you're importing the directory `Nmap`, not the file `Nmap.py`, as `mMod`, and therefore when you `getattr` from `mMod` you get `Nmap.py` not the class `Nmap`. Consider renaming to avoid this - modules should have `snake_case` names, only classes are `CamelCase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a structure like:

```
Plugin.py
/Nmap
    __init__.py
    Nmap.py
        # class Nmap(Plugin): ...
```

In `Plugin.py`, when you do `mMod = __import__(sPlugin, fromlist=[sPlugin])` where `sPlugin == 'Nmap'`, this makes `mMod` refer to the directory `/Nmap`, **not** the file `Nmap.py` (note that both files and directories can be modules in Python). Hence `mInstance = getattr(mMod, sPlugin)` makes `mInstance` the file `Nmap.py` rather than the class `Nmap`.

There are two ways to fix this, either:

1. Use the `__init__.py` in `/Nmap` to bring the class *"up"* one level, i.e. include `from Nmap import Nmap`; or
2. Add an extra level of `getattr` into `Plugin.py`.

Additionally, you should follow the [style guide's](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions, which might have helped you track the issue down faster.

Comment: You rock's ;). Thank you very much
And yes, you're right, I will change my directory name :)