# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for anaconda when I am trying to import networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Im getting this error when I try to import the networkx module

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.graph()
G.add_node(1)
```

The stack trace is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-11d4167b2e44> in <module>()
      1 from networkx import networkx
----> 2 G=nx.graph()
      3 G.add_node(1)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Its happening wwhen I try to run this on my jupyter notebook with the conda root environment although networkx has been installed in the environment

Comment: I hope this can give you more idea http://stackoverflow.com/q/4534438/7265539

Comment: I have already tried the suggestions given there
`from networkx import networkx`
Also tried `G=nx.networkx.graph()`

Comment: Have you tried this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8846613/7265539

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Graph` instead of `graph`.