# python - TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, scheduler

I want to use [rq_scheduler](https://github.com/ui/rq-scheduler) library in my app and this is my code :

```
import telepot
import sys
import time
import schedule
import datetime
from redis import Redis
from rq_scheduler import Scheduler


scheduler = Scheduler(connection=Redis())



def handle():
    print("hello")

def main():
    scheduler.enqueue_at(datetime(2017, 9, 11, 22, 41),handle)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

and I get this :
**update :**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "***\__init__.py", line 18, in main
    scheduler.enqueue_at(datetime(2017, 9, 11, 22, 41),handle)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

1- where is my mistake? why am I getting this ?

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable

Comment: it must be `datetime.datetime(...)`

Comment: @Akash In spirit, yes. I'd hesitate to close this has a duplicate of that question, though. There should be a Wikipedia article "List of Python classes named after their module".  :)

Comment: Use from datetime import datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime` is a module that also declares a class named `datetime`.

```
scheduler.enqueue_at(datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 11, 22, 41),handle)
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
...
schedule.enqueue_at(datetime(2017, 9, 11, 22, 41), handle)
```

In an ideal world, the class would have a PEP-8-compliant name (i.e., `datetime.DateTime`) to avoid the confusion.