# Socket Program not working

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a simple socket program, but it's not working. Can you please help.

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345             
s.bind((host, port))      

s.listen(5)              
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()    
   print ('Got connection from', addr)
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()
```

The below error I use to get.

```
s = socket.socket()        
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? I just copy-pasted it and it worked fine.

Comment: yes, even I copied pasted it from my pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
import socket

print(socket.__file__)
print(socket.socket)
```

in my environment, result is:

```
C:\Python27\lib\socket.pyc
<class 'socket._socketobject'>
```

Comment: In my computer result is 
  
  C:\Users\vWX442280\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py
    <class 'socket.socket'>

Comment: It's ok, so how did you get TypeError from `s = socket.socket() `? Do you have a TeamViewer?

Comment: Sorry, I cant use team viewer.

Comment: @Vivek You can try installing a clean official version of [python](https://www.python.org/), it may help to solve your problem quickly.