# Python 2 to Python 3 : TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I'm trying to modify a code which was written in Python 2 Language with the urllib2 module.I did modified my code with the module urllib in Python 3 but I'm getting error :

```
req = urllib.request(url)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What I am doing wrong here?

```
import urllib.request
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time

app_id = "172"
app_secret = "ce3" 


def testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token):

    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
    node = "/" + page_id
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters

    # retrieve data
    req = urllib.request(url)
    response = urllib.urlopen(req)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    print (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the lines

```
req = urllib.request(url)
response = urllib.urlopen(req)
```

to:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

You can find more information on this module **https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request
**https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen

Answer (score 0):

@kvmahesh's answer is absolutely correct. I'll just provide an alternate solution which supports both the versions. Use Python's `requests` library for making the call.

```
import requests
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time

app_id = "172"
app_secret = "ce3" 


def testFacebookPageData(page_id, access_token):

    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
    node = "/" + page_id
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters

    # retrieve data
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(response.text())

    print (json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

For detailed usage of requests: [Python `Requests` Docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Answer (score 0):

urllib.request is a module. You are calling the module on line 22...

```
req = urllib.request(url)
```

To fix do following:

1) Import at the top:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

2) then pass the url to urlopen(url)

```
# remove this line req = urllib.request(url)
response = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

3) See similar error here
[TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)