# Unable to install packages using pip for an unknown reason

Tags: python, pip

I am new to coding, and am trying to install matplotlib to help with a school project. I have installed packages using pip before, and I've never had any problem until now, when it says. I'm sure it's blindingly obvious but as I said I'm very new. Thank you

```
C:\Users\kiran>pip install matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: show the code that produced the error

Comment: C:\Users\my_name>pip install matplotlib

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` is an error message that occasionally occurs from a common typo of forgetting parens at the end of a method call or class instantiation. I.e.

```
import MyClass
o = MyClass
#instead of 
o = MyClass()
# OR
var = o.MyMethod
# Instead of
var = o.MyMethod()
```

Comment: I was trying to install a package tho

Comment: Ah. It may be related to [this know issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2924). What version of `pip` are you running?

Comment: Latest version. It was fine until i updated it yesterday

Comment: When i attempted to see the version this happend: pip --version
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\users\kiran\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "D:\Users\kiran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" --version'

Comment: Since this is Windows, I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling Python including pip.

Comment: Yeah, that worked perfectly. the old turn it off and on again lmao. Thank you