# How to call a class from a different file?

Tags: python, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a Blackjack project in Python.

I am trying to create my `Card.p`y object into my `Deck.py` object, but using:

```
from Models import Card


class Deck:
    # Global Properties of Deck
    __cards = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.__set_deck()

    # Get Methods
    def get_cards(self):
        return self.__cards

    # Set Methods
    def __set_deck(self):
        test = Card("Three", "Clubs")
        self.__cards.append(test)


obj = Deck()
```

with:

```
class Card:
    # Global Properties of Card
    __rank = ''
    __suit = ''

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.__set_rank(rank)
        self.__set_suit(suit)

    # Get Methods
    def get_rank(self):
        return self.__rank

    def get_suit(self):
        return self.__suit

    # Set Methods
    def __set_rank(self, rank):
        self.__rank = rank

    def __set_suit(self, suit):
        self.__suit = suit
```

gives me a `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` where I am creating the `Card` object.

Any suggestions? I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: If your class is in a file called `Card.py`, then `Card` is a module, and the `Card` class is inside it.

Comment: @khelwood I am not that proficient in python, but what does that mean? How can I create my Card class in my Deck class? Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

Here's how you would do it.

```
from Card import Card

Card()
```

The first Card represents the Card.py file while the second Card represents the Card class.

**Method 2**

You can also just import the Card file and call the card class from there on after such as so:

```
import Card

Card.Card()
```

Comment: The specific solution to my issue is:

from Models.Card import Card, this is because the Card module is inside a folder named Models