# Where did I go wrong in this tutorial?

Tags: python

I've been following a python tutorial, and the following code is essentially word for word from it (please excuse the silliness of it).  It wont run correctly, and I'd really like to have an understanding of where I've gone wrong, the errors being

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\corey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\corey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\corey\PycharmProjects\app\app.py", line 11, in <module>
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I haven't the slightest clue what could be wrong, and looking into the runpy file has not been helpful, as I have no idea what I'm looking at really.  here is the code itself:

```
import Question as Question

question_prompts = [
    "What color are flowers?\n(a) hopefully pink\n (b) teal\n\n"
    "Can you eat squids?\n(a) yeah, in japan\n (b)usually\n\n"
    "Is you messing wit a real one?\n(a) hell naw\n(b) you know it papi ;)\n\n"
]


questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
]


def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
        print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + " 3 my friend.")


run_test(questions)
```

and here is my "Question" datatype

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

please and thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Question.Question` to refer to the class? Also, `import Question as Question` is a bit pointless.

Comment: Did you mean `from Question import Question`?

Answer (score 0):

in your questions, you need to add a coma. Currently, it is recognized as a list with just one element.

```
question_prompts = [
    "What color are flowers?\n(a) hopefully pink\n (b) teal\n\n",
    "Can you eat squids?\n(a) yeah, in japan\n (b)usually\n\n",
    "Is you messing wit a real one?\n(a) hell naw\n(b) you know it papi ;)\n\n"
]
```

Full code:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

question_prompts = [
    "What color are flowers?\n(a) hopefully pink\n (b) teal\n\n",
    "Can you eat squids?\n(a) yeah, in japan\n (b)usually\n\n",
    "Is you messing wit a real one?\n(a) hell naw\n(b) you know it papi ;)\n\n"
]

questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "b"),
]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
        print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + " 3 my dude.")

run_test(questions)
```

also, the "as" operator in the import statement is there if you want to rename your import for readability.
`import Question as Question` is just the same as `import Question`

Comment: Thank you, that did it!  I think I understand how this works a bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
import Question as Question
```

is not doing what you think. The `import as` mechanism is a way to rename the way you use the module in your code. In this case you are redundantly telling it that you want it to import the module `Question` and refer to it as `Question` (which is the same name). It is not importing the `Question` class from the `Question` module.

So later when you do:

```
Question(question_prompts[0], "a")
```

you are trying to call the module, not the class inside the module. That is why you are getting the error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

You want to do it this way:

```
from Question import Question
```

That will import the `Question` class from the module into the namespace of your program and not anything else inside the `Question` module.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that was one of the few lines I had changed.  Much obliged