# (Python3) The command print does not work

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

If I type in the command print in a python script nothing happens. In tutorials there is always the message or the value they want, but when I do there is no command line that opens.

Example:

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.bot(command_prefix = "!bot")

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    
     print("bot is ready")
client.run("censoredtoken")
```

I think there should be a cmd window with the message: bot is ready.

Comment: How are you running that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-db73a0b68049> in <module>
      3 from discord.ext import commands
      4 
----> 5 client = commands.bot(command_prefix = "!bot")
      6 
      7 @client.event

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Check here for further hints:
[TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!bot")`