# can't install tlz module Python for Dask

Tags: python, dask

On Windows 10 Python 3.7.9 (IDLE) when I use Dask I isntall delayed first:

```
pip install delayed
```

Then I import: `from dask import delayed` but have an error:

> *Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in 
> from dask import delayed   File "C:\Python379\lib\site-packages\dask\delayed.py", line 7, in 
> from tlz import curry, concat, unique, merge ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tlz'*

I tried to install modules separately but installed only concat, unique and merge.

Comment: You clould try to install it via $. pip install dask-ml[complete]

Comment: @Avatazjoe How can I mark your answer? And it doesn't work properly? On linux it works: delayed(np.arange)(10) but on windows has an error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Comment: [see this]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows seem to be needed to run: `pip install tornado==4.5.1 distributed==1.21 dask-ml[complete]` too as [this coment](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/962#issuecomment-383522581) refers.

Also you need to import Delayed as:

```
from dask.delayed import delayed
```