# Python calling other python function error?

Tags: python

I am trying to call the python function `elevation2` (the file is called `elevation2.py` and the function `def elevation2`) in the same folder as my current file.

```
     import numpy as np         
     import elevation2
     def callgoogle(latmin,latmax,samples1, lngmin,lngmax,samples2):
      elev=[]
    if samples1 <= samples2:
        i = 0
        while i<samples1: 
            i = i+1
            w = latmin + i*(latmax-latmin)/samples1 
            if i == 1:
                elev = elevation2(w, lngmin,w,lngmax,samples2)
            else:
                elevo = elevation2(w, lngmin,w,lngmax,samples2)
                elev = np.c_[elev, elevo]                 
    else :
        i=0
        while i<samples2:
            i = i+1
            w = lngmin + i*(lngmax-lngmin)/samples2 
            if i == 1:
                elev = elevation2(latmin, w,latmax,w,samples1)
            else:
                elevo = elevation2(w, lngmin,w,lngmax,samples2)
                elev = np.c_[elev, elevo]     
    return elev
```

and the error I get is

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I wonder what that means?

The code in the elevation2 file is

```
import json as simplejson
import json
import urllib
import ssl


 ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


def elevation2(lat1, lng1,lat2,lng2,samples):
```

Comment: `import elevation2` means `elevation2` is a module, but you're attempting to call it when you do `elevation2(latmin, w,latmax,w,samples1)`. I think you meant to reference a function inside of that module instead.

Comment: this may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/42385016/13273054

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've added your `elevation2` code, the question is possible to answer.

The issue is that `elevation2` is a function *within* the `elevation2` module.

Therefore, try calling `elevation2.elevation2(...)` instead of `elevation2(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

elevation2 file

```
class Elevation2:
   ........ your code
   def yourMethod():
```

end elevation1 file

```
from Elevation2 import elevation2 

e=Elevation2()
e.yourMethod()
```

try this

Comment: putting a class Elevation2:  in front of the elevation2 file does not work. I added the code. It says then 'expected an intended block'