# SQL ALCHEMY- FAST API- API MODULE OBJECT NOT CALLABLE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

end point to test sql alchemy. Error reads: module object is not callable? also the query word isn't highlighted. The tutorial says I should do db.query(models.Posts).all() but that's not working either. normally vs code highlights and auto-completes so i know its connecting to the right object.

when i type in db.query() the ide doesn't recognise the query method? i even imported it manually from sqlalchemy.orm and it still isn't recognised?? everything else works fine, just testing the orm via the query method is bugging.

Error says :   File "C:****/**/***lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 747, in _connection_for_bind
conn = bind.connect()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'connect'

In the tutorial the teacher just types db. query(models.Post).all() and all the functions and methods are recognized. On mine query isn't recognized. Help please.

---

```
from logging import exception
from random import randrange
from tkinter.tix import STATUS
from typing import Optional
from urllib import response
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI, Query, Response ,status, HTTPException , Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import time
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, engine_from_config 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker,session , query

import models 
from database import ormengine , SessionLocal , get_db


@app.get("/sqlalchemy")
def test_post(db: session= Depends(get_db)):
    post = db.query(models.Post).all()
    return {"data":post}
```

---

models.py file is:

```
import string
from typing import Text
from xmlrpc.client import boolean
from database import Base, SessionLocal
from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP, Integer, PrimaryKeyConstraint, String, Boolean, Column 
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import null , text
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Text , TIMESTAMP

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__= 'apiproj2'

    id= Column( Integer , primary_key= True, nullable= False)
    title= Column( String, nullable= False)
    content = Column( String, nullable= False)
    published= Column(Boolean, server_default= 'True' , nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP( timezone=True), nullable= False , server_default= text('now()'))
```

---

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker 




 SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:naijalife@localhost/fastapi database"
    sqlalchemy_conn= 'postgresql://postgres:naija4life@localhost/fastapi database'
    ormengine= create_engine(sqlalchemy_conn)
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind= engine_from_config )
    Base = declarative_base()

# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Comment: Likely an issue with how you're importing a dependency. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534443/2479481

Comment: The error message you've included is nowhere in your code - include the code that actually produces the error. In your view you're also using `query` directly as a function and not calling it on the session. Since you haven't typed the session argument as a SessionLocal or similar, your IDE probably don't know what the actual type of the dependency returned from Depends is.

Comment: @MatsLindh i've added the extra code. I have no idea why it wouldnt recognise the query function, I've even tried importing it directly and it's not being recognised? im literally following the tutorial word for word.

Comment: You never call `engine_from_config` - you just give the function as the argument. You probably want to call it - `bind=engine_from_config()`. As I've mentioned, your IDE have no reason to know what `query` is from how it has been defined.

Comment: @MatsLindh I called the wrong engine, it was an error in the tutorial. I was calling engine from config instead of the engine I had created to connect to the database (orm engine). Thanks for your help mats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling the wrong engine, I should've called ormengine. The engine I created to connect to the database. The tutorial had an error in it. I changed this but it didn't work, after restarting vs code it worked. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the solution to your question.