# Calculate Levenshtein distance of two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, levenshtein-distance

I want to calculate the Levenshtein distance for two strings in two columns in a dataframe.
The dataframe looks like this (this is only a part of the data frame, it has approximately 4000 rows).

[image]

I want to use the Levenshtein method to get the Levenshtein distance for the strings in column "Source1" compared to "Source2"

Here is my code so far:

```
#import packages
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import Levenshtein as lev
import numpy as np

#Read excel file
df = pd.read_excel(xxx)
df.head(10)

#define arrays
a = df.Source1.to_numpy()
b = df.Source2.to_numpy()

#calculate Levenshtein distance between two arrays
for i,k in zip(a, b):
  print(lev(i, k))
```

**I get the following error:**

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [79], in <cell line: 6>()
5 #calculate Levenshtein distance between two arrays
6 for i,k in zip(a, b):
7  #  print(type(i), type(k))
----> 8   print(lev(i, k))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Can anyone please advise?

Jaay helped me in the comments. The solution is to use print(lev.distance(i, k))

Comment: can you post the data in dictionary please

Comment: have you tried to print(type(i), type(k)) ?

Comment: @Cadeyrn when I do that it gives me this: <class 'float'> <class 'str'>
<class 'str'> <class 'str'>

Comment: I don't know if this happens because some of the entries in the dataframe is NULL or NaN

Comment: how can it return 4 classes if there is only two variables?

Comment: So I replace the NaN with blanks, if I do print(type(i), type(k)) I get the following:<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
<class 'str'> <class 'str'> which shows everything is the same type.

Comment: When I do print(lev(i, k)) I get the following error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [79], in <cell line: 6>()
      5 #calculate Levenshtein distance between two arrays
      6 for i,k in zip(a, b):
      7  #  print(type(i), type(k)) 
----> 8   print(lev(i, k))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @Cadeyrn it prints more than 4 classes, it prints much more because there is about 4000 rows in the dataframe and this is supposed to calculate the distance between each two strings in all the rows

Comment: Hi, in your example 'lev' is the module name, this is not a function so its is not callable. Function may be lev.distance(i, k)

Comment: now it looks like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable

Comment: @Cadeyrn I tried this: import Levenshtein 
Levenshtein 
module 'Levenshtein' from 'C:\\Users\\Pauli.Duplooy\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Levenshtein\\__init__.py'>
Levenshtein.Levenshtein 
class 'Levenshtein._Levenshteinobject' 

from Levenshtein import Levenshtein 
Levenshtein class 'Levenshtein._Levenshteinobject' and got the following:   Input In [14]
    module 'Levenshtein' from 'C:\\Users\\Pauli.Duplooy\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Levenshtein\\__init__.py'>
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: have you tried what @Jaay said?

Comment: Hi yes I did, and it worked. I did say that in the edited question :)