# mediapipe.mp_holistic 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, mediapipe

```
def PoseEstimation(frame,win_name):
    
    with mp_holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5,min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic

        frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = holistic.process(frame)
        frame = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # 2. Right hand
        mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,22,10), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80,44,121), thickness=2, circle_radius=2)
                                 )
cv.imshow(win_name, frame)
```

My code is here

The Error is 
with mp_holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5,min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

What should i do so that i can use the module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `mp.solutions.holistic` as function instead of module.
I think, somewhere in your code, you have:

```py
mp_holistic = mp.solutions.holistic
```

Considering your snippet, I think you want to use the holistic call.

Consequently you have to change your:

```py
with mp_holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5,min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
```

with

```py
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5,min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
```

Comment: Yeah, i think this solves my bug. I wanna ask why this makes a difference. when i use the original line of code in main function, it works. when i use it in subfunctions, it fail with the above-mentioned error

Comment: you still don't understand the difference. the code is different, not the place it's used.