# How can I solve the error of ( 'module' object is not callable ) when i run the program?

Tags: python, keras

I have written the following code in the spider environment, but I am facing the following error when running.

#### My Code:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import models



### Generate random training an testing sets

x_train = np.random.random((1000,20))
y_train = np.random.randint(low = 2 , size = (x_train.shape[0] , 1))

x_test = np.random.random((100,20))
y_test = np.random.randint(low = 2 , size = (100 , 1))


### Defining layers of the MLP model

m = keras.models.sequential()
```

##### the Error is :

```
m = keras.models.sequential()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\hossein\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_464\416401841.py", line 1, in <module>
    m = keras.models.sequential()

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: `keras.models.sequential` appears to be a module, not a class. Did you mean this: https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/?

Comment: Its Sequential, not sequential, case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

"module object is not callable. Python is telling that code trying to call something that cannot be called. What is my code trying to call?"

try

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import sequential
```

for reference
[TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534438/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable)

Comment: thank you for helping... I tried the way that you helped ... but this error has been happend:                    AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'sequential'

Comment: Use tf.keras.models.Sequential()